# Why is my JSON object showing [Array] instead of the data in javascript after reformatting?

Tags: javascript, json, electron

Currently I am trying to create a JSON object in java script which has an additional array containing all of the data that I currently posses:

src is a JSON object which before any code is run is equal to:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("629ac43586b27bfd70337d06"),
    Title: 'Test Poll',
    Option: [ 'Test Option 1', 'Test Option 2', 'Test Option 3' ]
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("629afc9286b27bfd70337d09"),
    Title: 'Test Poll 2',
    Option: [ 'Test Option 1' ]
  }
]
```

I need to reformat this object so that it is contained within a separate array which I am currently attempting to do with this line:

```
  var context = { poll:src };
```

This results in a reformatting of the JSON object which I do not understand, after running this code context contains:

```
  poll: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("629ac43586b27bfd70337d06"),
      Title: 'Test Poll',
      Option: [Array]
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("629afc9286b27bfd70337d09"),
      Title: 'Test Poll 2',
      Option: [Array]
    }
  ]
```

It gets rid of the Option arrays and replaces them with [Array]. I need to keep these arrays and I am not sure what to change to fix this as I have tried looking elsewhere for answers. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: These *are* arrays. Your console is just shortening the output at certain depth.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me realize this, I was trying to use handlebars and didn't use implicit this because I thought this was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok they are arrays I am just too new to realize that it would not print fully. I was attempting to use handlebars on these Option arrays to print the list and I was forgetting to use the implicit this for the variable name instead of just 'Option'.

Problem solved.